# Error with logitmfx in R to calculate robust cluster standard error

Tags: r, database, regression, cluster-analysis, logistic-regression

I am hoping to run a logit regression which predicts the marginal effect at the mean of family size and age, and the effect of binary indicators (whether an individual is an immigrant, has health insurance, or smokes) on the predicted probability of developing hypertension.

This data comes from a clustered survey, and I am hoping to include robust clustered standard errors in the output.

But when I add the code to include robust cluster SE, I receive an error that the variables in my regression are not longer found and I'm not sure why. Any advice would be great! Thanks.

```
AGE       IMMIGRANT     FAMSIZE     HLTH_INS    HYPERTEN   SMOKE    PSU
<int>       <dbl>         <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>  <int>
40           0              2          1            0         0      2
23           0              2          1            0         0      1
24           0              2          1            0         0      2
18           0              3          1            1         0      2
30           0              2          1            0         0      2
33           1              6          0            0         0      1

#or if this is an easier output to reproduce:
structure(list(AGE = c(40L, 23L, 24L, 18L, 30L, 33L, 32L, 63L, 
22L, 24L), IMMIGRANT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), FAMSIZE = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), HLTH_INS = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), HYPERTEN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
    SMOKE = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), PSU = c(2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")


#The regression works without adjusting for clustered SE 
logit<-logitmfx(HYPERTEN~scale(AGE)+IMMIGRANT+scale(FAMSIZE)+HLTH_INS+
                 SMOKE,data=sample,
                atmean=TRUE,robust=T)


#However, when I add in the code to cluster SE I receive the error: "Error in scale(AGE) : object 'AGE' not found" 
logit<-logitmfx(HYPERTEN~scale(AGE)+IMMIGRANT+scale(FAMSIZE)+HLTH_INS+
                 SMOKE,data=sample,
                atmean=TRUE,robust=T,clustervar1="PSU", clustervar2=NULL,!is.null("PSU"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Trying to replicate the steps of the function using the source code, Steffen Moritz' solution should indeed work. The problem arises, since first `logitmfx` instantly calls another function `logitmfxest`.

This function has the same arguments, but it also has the following code:

```
if(!is.null(clustervar1)){
    if(is.null(clustervar2)){
      if(!(clustervar1 %in% names(data))){
        stop("clustervar1 not in data.frame object")
      }    
      data = data.frame(model.frame(formula, data, na.action=NULL),data[,clustervar1])
      names(data)[dim(data)[2]] = clustervar1
      data=na.omit(data)
    }
    if(!is.null(clustervar2)){
      if(!(clustervar1 %in% names(data))){
        stop("clustervar1 not in data.frame object")
      }    
      if(!(clustervar2 %in% names(data))){
        stop("clustervar2 not in data.frame object")
      }    
      data = data.frame(model.frame(formula, data, na.action=NULL),
                        data[,c(clustervar1,clustervar2)])
      names(data)[c(dim(data)[2]-1):dim(data)[2]] = c(clustervar1,clustervar2)
      data=na.omit(data)
    }
  }
```

From this the following code gets activated in your case:

```
if(!is.null(clustervar1)){
    if(is.null(clustervar2)){  
      data = data.frame(model.frame(formula, data, na.action=NULL),data[,clustervar1])
      names(data)[dim(data)[2]] = clustervar1
      data=na.omit(data)
    }
  }
```

This redefines "data" to be a data.frame build on the model.frame. But the model frame uses names from you formula, so suddenly column 2 is called **scale.AGE.** and column 3 is called **scale.FAMSIZE.**.

**This is a big problem** since the function then calls a generalized linear model:

```
fit = glm(formula, data=data, family = binomial(link = "logit"), x=T, 
        start = start, control = control)
```

where it uses your original formula containing scale(AGE) and scale(FAMSIZE), but with the new dataframe with the renamed columns.

So scaling before inputting should work. And indeed any other function will, as Steffen mentioned, cause the same error, since they will produce a similar renaming of columns when `model.frame` is called.

Comment: Very nice analysis! Pity the package has no github page to open an issue, they probably could have fixed this with a little effort in their next version.

Comment: @SteffenMoritz Agreed. The authors e-mail can be found, but it might be a bit intrusive to write him directly.

Comment: @Qwethm thank you for such an in depth explanation! I really appreciate it. The code runs now.

Answer (score 4):

Strange, somehow can't recognize the functions in the `formula` any more.
You can try this, if you remove `scale` it works fine. Also no other function like `log()` seems to work.

You could try calculating scale(AGE) before, then you don't need to put it in the formula.

Could look like this:

```
sample$AGE<-scale(sample$AGE)
sample$FAMSIZE<-scale(sample$FAMSIZE)

form <- as.formula(HYPERTEN~AGE+IMMIGRANT+FAMSIZE+HLTH_INS+SMOKE)
#However, when I add in the code to cluster SE I receive the error: "Error in scale(AGE) : object 'AGE' not found"
logit<-logitmfx(form,data=sample,
                atmean=TRUE,robust=T,clustervar1="PSU", clustervar2=NULL)
```

Comment: Thank you @SteffenMoritz! Things are running properly now.

Comment: Sorry I do actually have another clarifying question, from the R documentation ([https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mfx/versions/1.2-2/topics/logitmfx]) I read that in order to have cluster standard error I also need to include `!is.null(clustervar1)` at the end of the regression. But the sample you included does not. Is what you sent still calculating cluster SE?

Comment: I don't see this anywhere in the documentation...could you link this? You might have misunderstood the following: "If both robust=TRUE and !is.null(clustervar1) the function overrides the robust command and computes clustered standard errors."  It says that the clustervar1 argument shouldn't be NULL. Which it isn't, because it is "PSU".

Comment: Oh! I misunderstood the explanation, I thought '!is.null(clustervar1)` needed to be written in the equation. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.Yeah, probably they could have explained this clearer :D